# CORS: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check ( axios )

Tags: reactjs, laravel, axios

I'm building a SPA with Reactjs and laravel as API. I use axios to make API calls, some requests work without any issue, however on some pages when I make a request i'll receive a error that the the request is blocked by the CORS policy.

In laravel i'm using the `spatie/laravel-cors` package to add CORS headers so the preflight requests won't get blocked, by default it will allow any type of request from any origin.

Request:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const url = BACKEND_URL+API+'/XXX/';
        let headers = {
            "Authorization": "Bearer " + token,
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Accept": "application/json",
        }        
        axios({
            url: url,
            method: "GET",
            headers: headers,
            credentials: 'same-origin',
        })
         .then(response => {
          const data = response.data.data;
          this.setState({
            data: data,
            loading: false
          })
          })
          .catch(error => {
          console.log(error);
          });
    }
```

Expected response ( from localhost )

```
{
campaign_id: XXX
category: []
form_entry: {id: XXX, form_id: XXX, lead_id: XXX, fields: Array(1)}
form_entry_id: XXX
id: XXX
landing__page_id: XXX
last_contacted: "XXX"
name: "XXX"
notes: XXX
status: [{…}]
tag: []
}
```

Error message:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'XXX.XXX' from origin 'XXX.XXX' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

from localhost everything works fine with the same setup, the strange thing is that i'm only getting the errors once I put both front and backend online.

Anyone has a clue why this is happening?

Comment: Did you customize the `config/cors.php` configuration file? If so, what did you change?